# Make Django forget an incorrect 'makemigration'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-1.7

I'm working on a Django app where I've migrated my basic model. There is no data saved to the table representing this model (I'm using PostgreSQL). I've since added a new variable under the original model class, something like:

```
time_entered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I must entered a default time in an invalid format, maybe     `default = datetime.datetime.now()`, because Django gave me an error when I tried to migrate the new variable:

> Running migrations:
>   Applying app.0002_model_time_entered... Traceback:
>   ...
>   django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invali format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

I've commented out `time_entered`, I've used Django's timezone to set the default value to the correct format, and I've set the default value to a string in the correct format. Each time, when I try `makemigrations` and `migrate`, I get that same error and Django won't commit my changes to the database. I'm even getting the error when I try to look at the SQL commands with `sqlmigrate`. (To clarify, `sqlmigrate` works for recent `makemigrations` with minor changes, but not the early, uncommitted `makemigration` attempts that had the actual error.)

What can I do? How can I get Django to stop being stubborn and let go of that old, wrong SQL command? Is there a way to delete any uncommitted SQL commands from `makemigration`? I can't `migrate` anything right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used and unused migrations hang out in ./app/migrations. I deleted all migration files after the initial migration, then ran a new `makemigrations` that didn't have the format error.

I'm not satisfied with this as a solution. I'd still love to hear a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html

./manage.py schemamigration [myapp] --auto --update

rolls back the last migration